# How to query for an empty array in Cloud Datastore

Tags: node.js, google-cloud-datastore, google-cloud-platform

Can you filter for property with an empty array in a Google Cloud Datastore query?

```js
const query = datastore.createQuery('Task')
    .filter('arrayValue', '=', '');
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is not currently a way to filter empty arrays.

An alternative approach is to set empty arrays to the type 'null', then you will be able to filter for them.

Comment: Thanks, dan. It'd be great if this was added to the documentation. Probably could fit in super well [right here](https://cloud.google.com/datastore/docs/concepts/queries#array_values). :)

Comment: Noted, I'll file something to have it added.